# signal test environment for arduino?

Tags: io, arduino, diagnostics

I know this is a simple question with a very simple answer, but I am such a beginner I don't think I'm even able to effectively google. So please bear with me.

I'm just looking for some kind of diagnostic software for arduino. Not a virtual environment, I want to test the controller itself. Specifically, I'm learning about I/O and analog signals and want to test if the rotary potentiometer I hooked up is sending a 0-255 value (as programmed) to the controller when I turn it.

Does anyone have the name of a software of this type, where I can get real-time values from my analog inputs?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reading the input from the analog pin and printing on [Serial monitor](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) will do the trick.

Here is a simple code that I pulled from arduino docs that you might want to use:

```
/*
  AnalogReadSerial
  Reads an analog input on pin 0, prints the result to the serial monitor.
  Graphical representation is available using serial plotter (Tools > Serial Plotter menu)
  Attach the center pin of a potentiometer to pin A0, and the outside pins to +5V and ground.

  This example code is in the public domain.
*/

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

Please find full details of the code on this [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogReadSerial).